# Mod rewrite file as directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I'd like to redirect domain.com/file.php to domain.com/file/
I currently have this:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^file/?$ file.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

However, that only does half of the job, it only makes domain.com/file/ to load domain.com/file.php

I'd like it so domain.com/file.php would be redirected to domain.com/file/ (visibly change the URL)
And that would load domain.com/file.php

In other words "disallow" direct access to domain.com/file.php or at least make it seem like domain.com/file.php doesn't exist

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+file\.php
RewriteRule ^ /file/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Didn't work :( What is the condition looking for btw?

Comment: @user2263996 it is looking for what it says `/file.php`